How to show to Czech Embassy that I didn't overstayed my Visa (will these documents will be sufficient?)
Background of the problem: I went to France in September 2022 for 1-year Master's in a course in English language but I failed the degree due to very serious chronic health issues. I worked on my health while living in France and applied for same course and the universities which were offering english level courses and was selected in two universities and I chose one. Then I applied for 1 year extension to the visa in July 2023 and I was granted extension till 15 October 2023 on the condition that I will find a permanent accommodation. I found accommodation after searching for 1 month in last week of September 2023 and then I applied for visa extension. The visa office extended my visa till January 2024 as decision making takes time and then in November end 2023, my visa was extended till October 2024 and I was informed of the same on ANEF website, I just had to pay for a €50 Euros Stamp from a burocratic office as a payment and then get a stamp on my passport.
But when I joined the university, the professors told me that they can't give lectures in English. It became very very stressful as there was no help in English and my French level was not upto B2 level since I had applied to English language courses only. I became very depressed to the extent of being suicidal since the courses were not in English and the course incharge didn't even told me earlier despite being clearly asked in April 2023 before applying to their department.
Since I was suicidal, so I decided to drop out of course in 1st week of December and then by third week I decided to leave France permanently and on 18 December 2023, I came back to India and there is a stamp on my passport of the same. I didn't paid the 50 euros permanent visa sticker as I didn't intended to stay in France beyond January 2024 (till the month extension was given)
**
Now,the problem: I applied to some places for PhD program (not masters) and one place in Czech Republic offered me a place. I am in the process of applying long term visa for the same. How should I prove to the Czech embassy officials that I did not overstay my visa but was only in France till the time extension was given to me? Or I have committed a crime by not paying €50? I already paid visa processing fees in June 2023 at the time of extension of visa?

What's the concern? The fact that your exist stamp is later than the expiry of your visa? The gap between August and October? Do you have a copy of the permit covering the period September 2022-October 2023? Any documents for the time between October, 15, 2023 and October 21, 2023?


How should I prove to the Czech embassy officials that I did not overstay my visa but was only in France till the time extension was given to me?

I am not sure you have anything to explain at this point. Getting extensions or a grace period is extremely common and you have a document proving that France had no problem with you staying until January 2024. Importantly, you left the country on your own before the end of that period.

Or I have committed a crime by not paying €50? I already paid visa processing fees in June 2023 at the time of extension of visa?

Definitely not. It just means you abandoned your application and did not receive a visa but you left before the time covered in the récépissé so it should not be an issue.
If any of this come up, just explain as clearly as possible what happen. You don't necessarily need to elaborate on the mental health issues, just the fact that you face some personal issues, took care of applying for extensions and renewals of your visa and then decided to leave on your own to focus on getting better.
The one thing that could be called into question is your willingness and ability to complete the degree as you didn't do that last time you got a visa in Europe. Be prepared to explain that as calmly as possible.

Thank you very much for your answer."The one thing that could be called into question is your willingness and ability to complete the degree as you didn't do that last time you got a visa in Europe."  How should I prepare to answer this question?

@user It will depend on your situation and what you are comfortable sharing, e.g. show that you did complete a Masters's since, explain that you were unprepared for a program in French but that it's not an issue for a PhD, stress that you had personal issues but that you got better.
